# Как сделать два телеграмм бота в одном проекте?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Представим есть самый простой бот:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling()
```

А мне нужно примерно это:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
bot2 = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN2)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

@bot2.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo(message):
    bot2.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling()
bot2.polling()
```

Но в таком случае код не доходит до последней строчки, а уходит в бесконечный цикл первого бота

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед, данный код будет сложно поддерживать и создадите себе кучу проблем.

Comment: У вас какая-то проблема, вы сами придумали почти решение и создали новую проблему и спрашиваете теперь только о ней, но об исходной проблеме ни слова. Если сделать так `python3 bot1.py`, `python3 bot2.py` то ничего плохого не будет, эти 2 файла даже в одном репозитории можно оставить, это останется одним проектом..